# How to send notification to the browser of the selected user

Tags: php, push-notification, web-push, pushpad

I am using PushPad Web Push Notification service using `PHP`. I can easily push notifications but they are sent to all browsers. Lets say I have a lot of users.

```
user 1
user 2 
user 3
...
```

Now I want to send notification to just `User 1`. I cannot think of the idea how to do it. Can anyone give me a hint or idea of how this can be achievable? I asked my collegue but he says this is not possible in PushPad. I have no other means of getting information regarding this issue. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: According to their website it should be possible. Visit https://pushpad.xyz/ and scroll down to the "Sending push notifications" section. Then choose PHP and look at the code - as far as I understand its possible. (The section ir around the middle of the page) `# deliver to a user
$notification->deliver_to($user_id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can target specific users [as described in the docs](https://pushpad.xyz/docs/identifying_users).

## 1. Keep track of the user ID on subscription

When you subscribe a user to push notifications, attach some metadata to its subscription:

```
pushpad('subscribe', null, uid: 'User1', uidSignature: 'YOUR_SIGNATURE');
```

- You can use any string as the user ID (`uid`): in this example I use `'User1'`, but you can simply call it `'1'`
- The `uidSignature` can be generated using the PHP library: `Pushpad\Pushpad::signature_for($uid);`
- You can read more about the `pushpad('subscribe')` method and the similar `pushpad('uid')` method in the [Javascript SDK reference](https://pushpad.xyz/docs/javascript_sdk_reference)

## 2. Send notifications to specific users

When you send push notifications from your server (with the [PHP library](https://github.com/pushpad/pushpad-php)) you can target specific users:

```
$notification = new Pushpad\Notification(array(
  'body' => "Hello world!"
));

# deliver to a user
$notification->deliver_to('User1');

# deliver to a group of users
$notification->deliver_to(['User1', 'User2', 'User3']);
```